# undefined value from function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, return, console.log

I'm trying to get purchase order details from server

This is my code:

```
    function getPurchaseOrderInfo() {
      try {
        let po_ref = document.getElementById("po_ref").value;
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("po_ref", po_ref);
        data.append("request_token", request_token);
        fetch(URL_ROOT + "purchase-orders/get_purchase_order_info", {
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
            return msg.status ? msg.data : false;
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    console.log(getPurchaseOrderInfo());
```

[This is what I got by executing the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEWPZ.png)

I have no idea why I'm getting an undefined value instead of object shown at console.log(msg);

I need the object to print a table and show details to user

Comment: you're not returning anything. (return the fetch)

Comment: The `undefined` comes from `console.log(getPurchaseOrderInfo());` because that function doesn’t return anything. The `console.log(msg);` clearly logs the object below. `return msg.status ? msg.data : false;` doesn’t return anywhere; you discard that promise chain. Did you expect this `return` statement to somehow cross the function boundary of `(msg) => {`…`}`? Please see [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](/q/14220321/4642212).

Comment: can you explain me why?

Comment: Because functions without explicit returns always return undefined.

Comment: `return fetch(URL_ROOT ...` keep in mind it will return a Promise, you'll need to `getPurchaseOrderInfo().then(res => console.log(res));` Once in async land always in async land. (no wardrobes...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the fetch too. The return you're putting inside the then block returns to the fetch and not getPurchaseOrderInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise, hence the `.then()` is also a promise.
If you want to use the data to outside of the function you can  return the promise and use it anywhere you invoke the function.
Here’s one simple example with ES6 :

```js
function myFunc(){
    return fetch(…).then(res => res.json())
}

function anotherFunc(){
     myFunc()
        .then(data => {
             console.log(data);
         });
}
```

For side note, I personally prefer ES7 async/await, it is much more simpler for me.